# Insert output data from one table into one existing output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Data has to be inserted to this table:

```
FIELD2    |  FIELD3   |  Valley 1   | Valley 2 | Valley 3 |  Valley 4 | Valley 5 
----------|-----------|-------------|----------|----------|-----------|---------
Increments|           | NULL        |  NULL    |    NULL  |   NULL    |  NULL
```

OtherData     |s           | 4           |  4       |    4     |   4       |  4

Data To be inserted in:

```
Valley 1| Valley 2 |Valley 3|Valley 4|Valley 5
--------|----------|--------|--------|--------
22      |   NULL   |    NULL|   NULL |NULL
74      | NULL     |    NULL|   NULL |NULL
```

Output has to be :

```
FIELD2    |  FIELD3   |  Valley 1   | Valley 2 | Valley 3 |  Valley 4 | Valley 5 
----------|-----------|-------------|----------|----------|-----------|---------
Increments|           | 22          |  NULL    |    NULL  |   NULL    |  NULL 
          |           | 74          |  NULL    |    NULL  |   NULL    |  NULL
```

OtherData     |           | 4           |  4       |    4     |   4       |  4

suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or SQLite?

Comment: I don't get it. You want to update the existing record with 22 for valley 1, and then insert second record. Can you explain what's the logic here? Why is 22 "increments" and 74 is new record with field2 blank?

Comment: Need to add 2nd table to 1st table, so that i can read and display

Answer (score 0):

hmm, maybe you can try.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (V1,V2,V3,V4,V5) SELECT V1,V2,V3,V4,V5 FROM TABLE2
```

i cant see anything tricky in your question...
but if there is any required fields, then you need can simply insert hardcoded value in your query, for example a field F3 is required string, then you can modify the query to

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,F3) SELECT V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,'' FROM TABLE2
```